# Unable to view ActiveX program through Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, activex

I am connecting Remote Desktop to my home computer from work and trying to view an application that is ActiveX driven, but it does not work correctly. The application I'm trying to load is called DxClient Netviewer, it is a DVR software for security cameras. I can connect through RDP just fine, load up the software, enter in my username/password, but then nothing is displayed in the app. This happens on both the wep application and on the stand-alone installed application.

**Is there a setting through RDP or my home router that needs to be changed for this to work correctly?**

I'm going from a Windows 7 machine to another Windows 7 machine. My home router is a Linksys WRT120N firmware version 1.0.06.

Comment: Did you try looking at the advanced RDP connection options? AFAIK Dx and OpenGL can be transmitted in an RDP session, though the resulting images are laggy since they are rendered on the host computer.

Comment: @LeeHarrison after messing around with it more, I decided to go with TeamViewer. Works a lot easier and the program loads just fine. Didn't have to do any port forward on router either.